# Write the contents of an ArrayList to a text file

Tags: java, arraylist, filewriter

I have a list of some commands stored in an ArrayList and I have been trying to get this list printed in a text file. Below is the code-

```
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Commands.txt");
        for(String str: commandArray){
        writer.write(commandArray[i]);
    }
 }
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get no errors but the file isn't created either. Is there something I have done wrong. Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

EDITED QUESTION

@Sajal Dutta, I took your advice and came up with the following;

```
try {

    for(String str: movementArray){

        File file = new File("D://filename.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(str);
        bw.close();
    }
}

catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At The moment the file is created, but only the last value of from the arraylist is printed to the file. There are six values stored in the arraylist, how do I get all six of the to print out?

Comment: I don't see any typo. what are you on about?

Comment: Your for each loop is quite interesting. Couldn't understand how is it working.

Comment: I got the Idea from @Sajal. I don't fully understand it myself but it only seems to work partially. Only the last element from my arraylist is printed out as oppose to the entire list. There is a link on the comments to his answer below if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing-

```
finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Well.. you have to declare your writer outside your try..catch..finally block. Declare as FileWriter writer = null; and then in finally, if(writer != null) {try{writer.close();}catch(Exception e){//do whatever}}

Comment: @Hustl3r28 A better way to write to a file: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Comment: Thanks. But would it work with an arraylist, so insted of ("This is the content to write into file"), I have the name of my arraylist is the bracket?

Comment: @Hustl3r28 Yes, you'd do for(String str: commandArray){bw.write(str); } Then you close bw outside for loop.

Comment: I made some edits to the original question , if you could take a look, it would mean a lot thanks.

Comment: @Hustl3r28 You shouldn't have put it inside for loop. You are creating a new file in each iteration. Here's what it should have been:  String[] movementArray = new String[] {"123", "ABC", "DEF"};
  try {File file = new File("D://filename.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
     file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);    
    for(String str: movementArray){
     bw.write(str); 
     bw.write("\n"); // To print in a new line
    }    
    bw.close();} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();}

Comment: Note that I populated your movementArray with some strings for you to test with.

Comment: Thanks. It works now only it ignores the new line part of the code, so it just keeps printing contents of the arraylist on the same line without spaces.

Comment: @Hustl3r28 bw.write("\n"); should print a new line.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't seem to work that way in my case.

Comment: @Hustl3r28 Use bw.newLine(); instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
                if(!file.exists())
                    file.createNewFile();
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                for(String str : data){
                    bw.append(str);
                    bw.append("\n");
                }
                bw.close();
                writer.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time in the for loop you are creating a new FileWriter & BufferedWriter object which is not good